# Global Random Number for all test-cases

Tags: citrus-framework

I would like to have a global variable, to be used in all of my tests, hence I configured in: citrus-context.xml the following:

```
<citrus:global-variables>
    <citrus:variable name="myVariableName" value="citrus:randomNumber(3)"/>
</citrus:global-variables>
```

This seems to work, but the generated variable is changed to a new random number, everytime I refer to this variable.

```
${myVariableName} ${myVariableName} ${myVariableName}
835               165               516
```

What is the preferred way to generate a random number to be used in all tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own, by implementing a BeforeSuite. Thanks to this post here: [How should i pass variable extracted From Payload thru test classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429085/how-should-i-pass-variable-extracted-from-payload-thru-test-classes/49471292#49471292)
So, this is how I did this:

```
public class InitializationTest extends TestDesignerBeforeSuiteSupport {

    @Override
    public void beforeSuite(TestDesigner designer) {
        designer.createVariable("myGlobalNumber", RandomNumberFunction.getRandomNumber(3, true));

        designer.action(new AbstractTestAction() {
            @Override public void doExecute(TestContext testContext) {
                testContext.getGlobalVariables()
                        .put("myGlobalNumber", testContext.getVariable("myGlobalNumber"));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for reporting this!
Unfortunately you've found a bug in Citrus. It seems like the expression is evaluated every time the variable is called. This should not be the case. I've opened this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus/issues/535) to track the bug.

BR,
Sven

Comment: FYI: The issue has been fixed with https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus/issues/535.